# pandas groupby complex data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing the complex data:

```
                                                added                                            removed  test_num
57              [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]               [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        16
58              [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]               [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        17
59              [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]               [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        18
60                 [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]                  [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        41
61                 [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]                  [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        43
62                 [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]                  [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        44
63              [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]               [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        57
64              [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]               [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        64
65              [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]               [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        70
66              [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]               [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]        71
```

I want to reduce it by grouping:

```
df = df.groupby(['added', 'removed'])['test_num'].apply(list)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is there a way to group it by `[added, removed]`, or I should transform it to something different?

Comment: Which version of Pandas are you running it with? I just tested your code here, using Pandas 0.22.0 and it worked fine. I simply copy-pasted your data into a csv file, and then `df = pd.read_csv('example_data.csv')`.  After that, I ran the groupby&apply(list) command and it worked fine.

Comment: @GabrielaMelo the version is 0.22.0. It seems that you read the data as strings, I wanted to post the print output, but it does not fit to the screen, so I saved it to a file and posted here.

Comment: @GabrielaMelo I added print output.

Comment: Instead of printing your whole data, you should make some example data of 5-10 rows which represents your problem. This way your problem is not reproducible and can even get close votes.

Comment: Your `added` and `removed` columns are list of dictionaries, which is not ideal for pandas anyway. I recommend you to flatten the data structure first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert your lists to string so we can `groupby` on it. And after that convert it back to `list` type with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
df[['added', 'removed']] = df[['added', 'removed']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str))

grp = df.groupby(['added', 'removed'])['test_num'].apply(list).reset_index()

grp['added'] = grp['added'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
grp['removed'] = grp['removed'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

**output**

```
                                   added                               removed                      test_num
0  [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]  [{'elem': [6, 8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]  [16, 17, 18, 57, 64, 70, 71]
1     [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 150.89}]     [{'elem': [8, 9], 'dose': 192.0}]                  [41, 43, 44]
```

Then if we check the type of one value, we get list:

```
type(grp['added'].iat[0])

list
```

**Note**:

Pandas is not constructed to have list of dicts as values, you should probably take a step back and flatten your data like already mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Based on our conversation in the comments, I conclude that your 'added' and 'removed' columns contain actual list data in the CSV file from which you are reading. When you load the CSV into a DataFrame, pandas adds the quotes in display which makes them look like strings, but those objects are actually treated as lists. Thank you for clarifying that point.

Basically, you cannot group by values that are not hashable (sort of like how a `dict`'s keys have to be hashable). You can convert them to strings for the purpose of doing the `groupby`, then convert them back after, yes.

I advise reformatting your data. The `pandas` package is not great with iterable objects as values as evidenced by your issue (and by many other limitations you can find around SO). PANel DAta is best (hence the name `pandas`), and at first glance, your data looks convertible.

Anyway, these two lines will fix your problem. Before you run the `groupby` method:

```
df['added'] = df['added'].astype(str)
df['removed'] = df['removed'].astype(str)
```

Then after you get the new `df`, you have to convert the columns back to `list` values.

Comment: But I want to use this data later, so I should transform it back to its initial structure?

Comment: @MichaelO. Did this work for you? It's not clear to me from the example. It looks to me like pandas is confused about the types of those two columns. Did you mean for them to be strings? If not, why are the values the wrapped in quotes?

Comment: I edited it and added print output, as much as my screen lets this.

Comment: @MichaelO. That does not answer any of my questions. If anything it obfuscates the problem because when you print a DataFrame, quotes are not added around string values. I am asking (1) if you tried my solution (2) if it worked and (3) why in your original post were the values in 'added' and 'removed' columns wrapped in quotes (i.e., are they in your data source or did you add them)?

Comment: (1) yes. I tried it (2) it worked (3) in my original post I used `to_csv` method which adds quotes to lists so Pandas is interpreting everything as strings. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @MichaelO. Amended.